# AWS Athena Timestream Connector example

Tags: amazon-athena

Has anyone used AWS Athena Timestream Connector, can you please share example for the usage.
I tried the below github link but didn't found detailed example for it.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/tree/master/athena-timestream

Can anyone share example for Aws Athena Timestream Connector